# Model - View - Controller new perspective

Tags: php

Good Morning everyone. Recently i've read an article about mvc pattern saying that most of the php frameworks out there implemented the mvc pattern wrong.
[php master mvc pattern part 1](http://phpmaster.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-2/)
[php master mvc pattern part 2](http://phpmaster.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)
Well after reading this and looking over that implementation a question appeared.
How on earth would call in the view the method called in model? What i'm trying to say is this.
This is a piece of code from the article.

```
<?php
$model = $_GET['model'];
$view = $_GET['view'];
$controller = $_GET['controller'];
$action = $_GET['action'];

if (!(empty($model) || empty($view) || empty($controller) || empty($action))) {
    $m = new $model();
    $c = new $controller($m, $action);
    $v = new $view($m);
    echo $v->output();
}
```

let's say we've written a small implementation of this design pattern after reading the article and we have the following code:

```
<?php
class Index extends Controller
{
   public function __construct(IndexModel $model, $action)
   {
       $this->model = $model;
   }
   public function someAction($id)
   {
       $this->model->getData($id);
   }
}
class Index extends View
{
   public function __construct(IndexModel $model, $action)
   {
       $this->model = $model;
   }
   public function someAction()
   {
       $this->model->getData();
   }
}
class Index extends Model
{
   public function __construct()
   {
        //Some Code Here
   }
   public function someAction()
   {
       // Inserting Data into database.
   }
}
```

As you can see we are calling the same method both in controller and in view to get the data from the database. But if i know correctly the view should take care of the controller's job so the $id wouldn't be right to parse it again in the view or something like that. Then how this can be solved?

Comment: That's a terrible "implementation" of MVC too and is far from correct as well

Comment: which part? the code from the article or the code part with classes ? :D

Comment: I agree it's  a bad implementation; but technically speaking, in MVC there is nothing preventing you from accessing the model through the view. You might want to check MVP(Model-View-Presenter) to ensure that your workflow goes always through the Presenter( similar as Controller in MVC)

Comment: Both, especially your first block of code though. You don't instantiate M, V *and* C from request parameters. The request parameters determine only the controller which gets instantiated, the controller then decides which model action needs to be invoked and which view should handle the presentation. The view doesn't need the controller for anything, since the controller's job is essentially done with the above and does not need to be called from the view or elsewhere.

Comment: the first piece of code was from the article it's not mine .. the second one is mine and it's only for the example. i don't remember mvc included the routing part that's another thing.. bot piece of code were meant to describe the ideea of the approach and the main question was how on earth in this approach would handle the requesting data from the model since you call it in the controller but you need to tell the view to output it. and that would mean that you would call in the view too if i'm not mistaken. correct me if wrong and please explain to me.

Comment: And why the second piece of code isn't good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no 1:1 correlation between controllers and parts of the model (note: *not* "models" but *parts of _the model_*). Just because you have an "index controller" doesn't mean you need an "index model" and "index view".
2. The M, V and C are not constructed together. The controller is constructed, and then *it* decides which model method to load/construct/invoke and which view should respond to the request.

   1. There's discussion about whether the controller should invoke the view, or whether the model should "update" the view. Since web requests are ephemeral and there's no "constant" view, the latter makes little sense in PHP; it's more appropriate for the original SmallTalk or Obj-C or similar environments.
3. The first code snippet has terrible use of `empty` (see [here](http://kunststube.net/isset)) and, again, should not construct all parts together.

MVC should be approached like this:

- The model *is* **the app**. It's not just a "data handler" or "data store", it is the core app. Everything the app does, business logic wise, is "the model". This includes sending email notifications, database maintenance work and such auxiliary things, they're all in the model.
- The view is responsible for producing output of various forms. The view should be able to interact with the model to get the data it needs to do its job. Data should not be "pushed into" the view, the view should be able to "pull" the data it needs; otherwise something external to the view needs to know what data the view needs, which means the view logic is not self contained in the view anymore.
- The controller is just the little bit of glue that's left to invoke the correct model method and view in response to the incoming request.

I typically structure these parts like this:

- The model consists of various parts, including data storage handlers, "primitives" (classes that model individual business objects) and "services". The "services" contain all the "actions" your app can do and form the model API. Whenever you want to "do" something in the app like "register a user" or "fetch all records for date range X through Y", there's *one* specialized method for it in the service API. Just looking at this service API you should be able to enumerate all the things your app "does".
- There's one object which is either a "dispatcher" or a "service locator" or simply a dependency injection container that simplifies instantiation of these service classes and allows someone to call them. The controller gets one of these and so does the view.
- There's a router which does some "rough routing" based on the URL, invoking a controller method. The controller further looks at the details of the request and decides to call a model method and/or to respond with a view.
- The view may decide the best way to present some data based on the specifics of the request, e.g. whether to respond with an HTML page or a JSON data blob. Yay for RESTful services.

In rough pseudo code:

```
$r = new Router;
$r->route($_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER); // or something like that
```

This dispatches to something like:

```
class FooController {

    public function __construct(ServiceLocator $services) { ... }

    public function bar(Request $request) {
        $request->assertIsPost();
        $this->services->locate('Baz')->froogleTheWibbles($request->getPostParams());
        (new BarView($this->services))->displayWibbles($request);
    }

}

class BarView {

    public function __construct(ServiceLocator $services) { ... }

    public function displayWibbles(Request $request) {
        switch ($request->accepts()) {
            case 'html' :
                $this->loadTemplate(...);
                ...
            case 'json' :
                echo json_encode($this->services->locate('Baz')->getWibbles());
        }
    }

}
```

And the model does whatever it needs to do...

```
class Baz {

    public function froogleTheWibbles(array $data) {
        foreach ($data as $wibbleData) {
            $wibble = new Wibble($wibbleData);
            $this->wibbleStore->save($wibble);
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

There is no "one answer" for MVC, the important part is that the model contains everything your app "does" independent of input and output, the view can produce the right output as requested as independently as possible and the controller is just the little bit of glue that handles input conditions. There are various ways in which this can be realized. The important design principle should be the realization that the view and controller are interchangeable to fit different conditions (web page, JSON API, XML API, SOAP API, CLI invocation, ZeroMQ node etc.), but "the model" is not.

Comment: I dont aggree that things like sending mails belongs to the model and that a controller is just "glue". Imagine different controllers accessing the same model, first needs an email sent, second doesn't. Look at Zend2 in combination with Doctrine for example. There is no business logic inside the model.

Comment: No business logic inside the model?! That appears to be missing the point of MVC entirely. Business logic is all the model is about! Again, the controller is *interchangeable* depending on how you want to expose your app's services. You have a web page which lets a user do something, but you also have an XML API that lets apps do the same thing. The *input* is quite different and needs to be handled differently, but the action is the same. If you keep the business logic in the controller, you need to duplicate it. No, the BL goes in the model, the controller adapts based on the input format.

Comment: You need something like *request router -> input format adaptor -> business logic [ -> data store ] -> output*. The first two are the job of the controller, the business logic and data store and everything else "core app-y" is the model. If you have this separation but are calling the thing with the business logic "controller", it's just a mislabeling according to the original MVC idea. In my case what you call "controller" I seem to be calling "model services".

Comment: The important part is not really what it's called, but that concerns are properly separated. If you have several very different input types (XML, POST data and, say, data entered on the CLI), standardizing this data into a common format and acting on it with business logic are two separate things. If you have both in one "controller", that's bad. You need one part which handles the input format and another common business logic handler, in my above explanation the former is the controller (interchangeable) and the latter the model [service] (one and only).

Comment: First of all the first piece of code is taken from that article and posted here for everyone to see on short how the implementation should be as an ideea for you guys to see how the routing part works.. in procedural code. Second of all stop going off the subject the controller is only a glue for the v and m. it shouldn't be any logic in there. Any one heard of the ideea ... - - skinny controller  fat models - - ??

Comment: @Bogdan I'm not accusing you of that first piece of code, but I'm criticizing it all the same. :)

Comment: i see well the second piece the one that i wrote was pulled fast for example to discuss on it :-d and my primary question still remains how you parse the data to the view if you called the model in the controller since there you parse the "id of the record from db" and if you would do the same in the view the you would take the responsibility of controller and put into the view ( which would be wrong ). and this makes me say that the existing framework maybe they didn't get it wrong well not entirely the concept of mvc they only found a work around for this problem.

Comment: @Bogdan The controller should trigger some *action* in the model if some data needs to change. If nothing needs to be changed, the controller doesn't need to do anything basically. It then just loads the appropriate view, pass all the necessary objects to it so the view can get the data it needs, and then let the view do its thing. So you're never doing the *same thing* in the view and controller anyway. In controller, say, `$FooModelService->updateData($request->data);`, in the view: `$FooModelService->getCurrentData()`.

Comment: and the id of the record that i want to get using getCorrentData() where do i need to parse it ? :-) since i'm using that method in the view and not in the model and that doesn't break the responsibility of the controller?

Comment: Then pass it into your view. The view needs to accept whatever parameters it needs to accept to do its job. For example: `WibbleView::displaySingleWibble($id)`. Then the controller needs to pass in the `$id`, and the view gets the data for this wibble as needed.